# What evidence is there that the "woman" in Revelation 12 refers to Israel / the Church?

Tags: revelation

A recent question ([Did any of the Early Church Fathers believe that Revelation 12:1-5 is about the Virgin Mary?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96881)) asks about early identification of the woman in Revelation 12, which Roman Catholics traditionally identify as the "Queen of Heaven", and more specifically, Mary, the virgin mother of Jesus.

One user commented in response that "generally in symbolic prophecy, women represent religions or churches".

Therefore, I would like to ask the opposite question. **What evidence exists,** either in scripture or early writings, **that the entity in Revelation 12 is a reference to the Church, and *not* to Mary?**

Comment: Certainly this can symbolize many things to one's interpretation or insights, including those of the Early Church.

Comment: @Dottard, instead of voting to close because a question relates to a specific denomination's beliefs, maybe you could vote to close it as a duplicate. Now that it's on BH (a site to which I didn't belong until just now), I see that either https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2037 or https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63357 look like likely candidates. (I don't seem to have any way to close it myself.)

Comment: I have removed my close vote and am composing an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the rest of ch12, the same woman is pursued by the dragon, which should be taken as representing the persecution described in ch13. He wants his revenge for being thrown from his accusing office by "the blood of the Lamb" and the testimony of the gospel (v10, v13)

She then experiences events which evoke the experience of God's people Israel in the time of the Exodus, when they were escaping the persecution of Pharaoh.

She is given the wings of an eagle to aid her in her escape. This echoes "I bore you on eagles' wings and brought you to myself" (Exodus ch19 v4).

The serpent tries to sweep her away with a flood. This echoes "Egypt rises like the Nile, like rivers whose waters surge. He said, i will arise, I will cover the earth..." (Jeremiah ch46 v8)

But the earth opens up and swallows the river. This echoes "The earth swallowed them" (Exodus ch15 v12).

Finally, of course, she escapes into the wilderness, where she is nourished by her God.

In short, she is experiencing in allegory the kind of suffering and rescue experienced by that corporate woman who represents God's people in many of the prophets, especially the Israel of the time of Moses.

We have no evidence that it reflects what Mary herself experienced in person.

Answer (score 1):

**What evidence is there that the "Queen" in Revelation 12 refers to Israel or the Church?**

While the Catholic Church recognizes the "***woman***" as part of the polyvalent symbolism that is found in the book in four referents: Israel, the Church, Eve, and Mary, other interpretations may possibly exist in other denominations also.

One Early Church interpretation of the woman as the “**church**” is [Hippolytus of Rome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolytus_of_Rome) (170-235) who states said interpretation in [On Christ and Antichrist](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0516.htm):

> 60. Now, concerning the tribulation of the persecution which is to fall upon the Church from the adversary, John also speaks thus: And I saw a great and wondrous sign in heaven; a woman clothed with the sun, and the moon under her feet, and upon her head a crown of twelve stars. And she, being with child, cries, travailing in birth, and pained to be delivered. And the dragon stood before the woman which was ready to be delivered, for to devour her child as soon as it was born. And she brought forth a man-child, who is to rule all the nations: and the child was caught up unto God and to His throne. And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she has the place prepared of God, that they should feed her there a thousand two hundred and threescore days. And then when the dragon saw it, he persecuted the woman which brought forth the man- child. And to the woman were given two wings of the great eagle, that she might fly into the wilderness, where she is nourished for a time, and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent. And the serpent cast (out of his mouth water as a flood after the woman, that he might cause her to be carried away of the flood. And the earth helped the woman, and opened her mouth, and swallowed up the flood which the dragon cast) out of his mouth. And the dragon was angry with the woman, and went to make war with the saints of her seed, which keep the commandments of God, and have the testimony of Jesus.
> 61. By the woman then clothed with the sun, he meant most manifestly the Church, endued with the Father's word, whose brightness is above the sun. And by the moon under her feet he referred to her being adorned, like the moon, with heavenly glory. And the words, upon her head a crown of twelve stars, refer to the twelve apostles by whom the Church was founded. And those, she, being with child, cries, travailing in birth, and pained to be delivered, mean that the Church will not cease to bear from her heart the Word that is persecuted by the unbelieving in the world. And she brought forth, he says, a man-child, who is to rule all the nations; by which is meant that the Church, always bringing forth Christ, the perfect man-child of God, who is declared to be God and man, becomes the instructor of all the nations. And the words, her child was caught up unto God and to His throne, signify that he who is always born of her is a heavenly king, and not an earthly; even as David also declared of old when he said, The Lord said to my Lord, Sit at my right hand, until I make Your enemies Your footstool. And the dragon, he says, saw and persecuted the woman which brought forth the man- child. And to the woman were given two wings of the great eagle, that she might fly into the wilderness, where she is nourished for a time, and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent. That refers to the one thousand two hundred and threescore days (the half of the week) during which the tyrant is to reign and persecute the Church, which flees from city to city, and seeks conceal-meat in the wilderness among the mountains, possessed of no other defense than the two wings of the great eagle, that is to say, the faith of Jesus Christ, who, in stretching forth His holy hands on the holy tree, unfolded two wings, the right and the left, and called to Him all who believed upon Him, and covered them as a hen her chickens. For by the mouth of Malachi also He speaks thus: And unto you that fear my name shall the Sun of righteousness arise with healing in His wings.“

Some Dispensational Premillennialists, and Amillennialists who believe in multiple valid interpretations will often identify the woman as the nation of Israel. There are several reasons given to support this interpretation. The woman is said to be clothed with the sun, the moon under her feet, and twelve stars. These symbols are drawn from Genesis 37:9–11, in which Joseph has a dream of the sun and moon symbolizing his father and mother, and stars representing his eleven brothers, which bow down to him. The Old Testament's prophets referred to Israel as a "woman" (Isaiah 54:5–6; Jeremiah 4:31; Micah 4:9–10). See: [Who's That Woman?](https://web.archive.org/web/20080724191510/http://www.biblicist.org/bible/woman.shtml):

> **The Woman and National Israel**
>
> Dispensational Premillennialists identify the woman of chapter twelve as representing national Israel. There are several sound reasons to support this interpretation:
>
> 1. In chapters eleven through fourteen the prophetic book is dealing specifically with the nation of Israel. Both the city of Jerusalem and its Temple are in focus. And to support the idea that God is again dealing with the nation of Israel, the temple (lit. sanctuary) of God in heaven is opened revealing the ark of the covenant. A sign that God has not forgotten His unconditional covenant relationship with that nation.
> 2. The woman in Rev. chapter twelve is said to be clothed with the sun, and the moon under her feet. These symbols were frequently used in the Old Testament in association with national Israel (Jer. 31:35-36), and especially in Gen. 37:9-10 where they are seen as a direct reference to Jacob and his sons, the progenitors of the covenant nation. In Ps. 89:35-37 God makes an everlasting covenant with King David stating that his throne will endure as the sun before Him and be established forever like the moon.
> 3. On the woman's head is a crown of twelve stars which represents the twelve tribes of Israel. And the fact that they are set in a crown (Gr. stephanos) on the woman's head signifies Israel's future triumph through Christ on earth during the coming Millennial reign when the Son will rule the nations (cf. Rev. 12:5) from David's throne in Jerusalem (Lk. 1:32-33; Is. 49:1-13; Zech. 1:14-17; 2:8-13; 8:1-8, 20-23; 14:16).
> 4. The Church is called a "bride," or a chaste virgin, but it is Israel that is referred to in Scripture as a "woman" (Is. 54:5-6; Jer. 4:31; Mic. 4:9-10).
> 5. The symbol of the dragon standing before the woman is revealed as Satan (12:9), and in the Old Testament Satan is pictured as national Israel's adversary (1 Chron. 21:1; Zech. 3:1-2) as well as that of Israel's Messiah (the male child the woman gives birth to) during His earthly ministry (Lk. 4:13).
> 6. The woman flees into the wilderness where she is nourished for 1260 days, the equivalent of three and a half years or forty-two months (cf. Rev. 11:1-3). These terms are used prophetically in Scripture either for the first half or the last half of the "Seventieth Week of Daniel," in Dan. 9:24-27. A prophecy specifically addressed to Daniel and his people, Israel (Dan. 9:24).
>
> In the latter part of the seventieth week a remnant of Israel will flee into the wilderness to escape the persecution of Antichrist, who is called "the son of destruction," "the lawless one," and "whose coming is in accord with the activity of Satan" (2 Thess. 2:1-12; cf. Rev. 12:4, 9). Jesus, in the Olivet discourse, warned the people of this time which would occur just prior to His return to set up His earthly, Millennial kingdom (Matt. 24:15-22).
>
> 7. Michael the archangel is called the guardian over the sons of Israel in Dan. 12:1. And he will arise at that time of national Israel's tribulation (Dan. 12:1; cf. Rev. 12:7).

Comment: Thanks for setting out the dispensation view.  However, I cannot see how any of this excludes the Christian church.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, a few misconceptions could helpfully be cleared away. The chapter never says that this symbolic 'heavenly woman' is a queen. She is crowned with a crown of 12 stars, but she is never called a queen. There IS a symbolic woman in Revelation (18:7) who calls herself a queen - she who is the antithesis of this heavenly woman, namely, Babylon the Great city ruling over the nations.

Second, the Catholic church is cautious about ascribing to Mary the application of the 'heavenly woman' of chapter 12. To quote:

> "It is difficult to say whether Mary is meant by the woman of the Book
> of Revelation. The woman probably stands primarily for Israel and then
> for the Church itself." *Encyclopedia of Theology* Edited by Karl
> Rahner, p. 896, article 'Mariology' by Michael Schmaus, Burns & Oates,
> London, 1981

One reason why it might be tricky for the Catholic church to say Mary is that woman of Revelation chapter 12, is that verse 17 goes on to say that she has 'offspring' (seed) further to the male child born to her in heaven and snatched away to God's throne. If Christ was literally her 'seed', then how come she bore others, as 'the rest of her seed'?

Scriptural statements give evidence for grasping who this symbolic heavenly woman is, with the book quoted below suggesting that she incorporates (symbolically) Eve, Sarah, Mary, and the Bride of Christ (which is his 'body', the Church). First, the author points out that Joseph had a dream about the sun, moon and eleven stars bowing down to him. His parents and brothers were enraged, knowing what the application signified! This is in Genesis 37:9-11.

> "Here ***Jacob, which is Israel***, is depicted as the sun; Joseph's
> mother as the moon; his eleven brethren as the eleven stars, of which
> he himself therefor, ***a figure of Christ***, was the twelfth. These
> all signify the father of Israel, the mother, and the children of
> Israel, as the sun, moon, and twelve stars.... Distinct from her [in
> Rev. ch.12] but of her glory; if so, ***Israel was her heritage.***
>
> But the heritage of the woman is distinct from that woman... The sun,
> the moon, and the twelve stars which formed her heavenly raiment are
> not to be confused with the heavenly woman thus arrayed... *They*
> speak (from Joseph's dream) of the glory of Israel. But of what does
> *she herself* speak?" *The Revelation of Jesus Christ*, p.278-9, John Metcalfe http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Then comes explanations about Eve, and Christ being the seed of the woman, concluding that: "***The heavenly woman in the vision of Revelation surely corresponds with mystical Eve***, the mother of all living, in whose hearing the Lord God said to the serpent 'I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed... (Genesis 3:15)." (p.280) Metcalfe continues:

> "Some have conjectured that the heavenly woman is Israel. However
> Israel was not heavenly, but earthly. Again, the signs of Israel, from
> Joseph's dream, of the sun, moon and twelve stars, are not the woman
> herself, but that with which she was adorned. But the woman is more
> than her vestments. So that ***she may incorporate much that is of
> Israel, but she herself remains a vastly transcendent concept... The
> heavenly woman still answers to Eve in the beginning***...
>
> Nevertheless it is true that Mary was the visible earthly culmination
> of a heavenly series of visionary prophecies spanning the whole of
> time and incorporating increasing openings from the beginning of
> scripture, finding its transcendent expression in the twelfth chapter
> of Revelation. In such vast and divine imagery, the visionary heavenly
> woman of necessity ***includes Mary, just as it does Eve, but the
> graphic imagery of the mysterious vision vastly transcends the
> individual***.
>
> Others proclaim with loud Protestant pride (for they will not have it
> that she is Mary) that the woman is the Church. What utter nonsense.
> The church bears the man child?... Then, since Adam preceded Eve,
> ***Christ of necessity preceded the Church. How then could she have borne him, when she did not so much as exist until the ascension?***"
> (*Ibid.* p.281-2  All bold italics mine)

Then Metcalfe spends more pages dealing with the role of Sarah, and Jerusalem above (heavenly Jerusalem). This latter point, about spiritual Zion, is the supreme concept involved in Revelation chapter 12. I cannot possibly quote enough to do justice to the argument, but must conclude with a summary paragraph in the book:

> "In fine, the great sign of the heavenly woman in the vision of
> Revelation chapter 12 depicts her as the symbol of that reality, that
> heavenly totality of divine thoughts, which brought Christ down from
> heaven. She is the origin of his coming forth, the opening of truth
> which was the cause of his being born as man. Out of the womb of
> ancient, lingering, divine promise, truth, and purpose, *nothing but
> the coming of Christ* yielded fulfilment and brought consummation to
> its fulness... In a word, *she is the concept that bore Christ and his
> seed*, called heavenly Jerusalem, and spiritual Zion." (*Ibid.* p.288
> Italics the author's)

Answer (score -1):

The identity of the "woman" of Rev 12 is determined by her description in the text, namely:

- V1: clothed in the sun
- V1: moon under her feet
- V1: chaplet (στέφανος not διάδημα, see Rev 12:3, 13:1, 19:12) of 12 stars
- V2: pregnant and about to give birth
- V2: crying in pain of child-birth
- V4: Dragon (= Devil, Satan, Serpent as per V9) stands ready to devour the child as soon as it is born
- V5: she gives birth to the son who would rule nations with an iron scepter (see Ps 2 - a reference to Messiah) and the child caught up to God's throne (see Acts 7:55, Rev 5, etc)
- V6: she flees into the wilderness for 1260 days, or times, times and half a time (V14)
- V13: dragon pursues the woman after being thrown out of heaven
- V14: woman given two great wings of an eagle to flee to the wilderness
- V15, 16: woman saved from drowning by the earth who swallows the dragon's river
- V17: dragon goes to make war on the rest of the woman's children (who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus)

Now, it is immediately obvious that the description of the woman of Rev 12 uses highly figurative and symbolic language.  There is little dispute that the male child is a direct reference to Messiah, Jesus Christ.  But who or what is the woman?

There have been two broad views:

- that of the Roman Catholic Church who believe that the woman of Revelation 12 is Mary, the mother of Jesus
- that the woman is a general symbol of the true "church" or people of God - Israel in the OT and spiritual Israel in the NT and Christian era.

It is now obvious that Mary the mother of Jesus does not fully fulfill all the descriptions listed above.  It is for this reason that many non-Catholics have understood the woman of Rev 12 as God's people generally, both as literal Israel in the OT and spiritual Israel in the NT, ie, God's true people throughout the ages.

God's church has always been persecuted by the Satan and his agencies as described in Rev 12.  Indeed, even to this day, myriads of Christians are languishing in prison around the world, some being tortured for their faith.

For some indication about what some the early church fathers believed, see appendix 2 below.

**APPENDIX 1 - Woman as a Symbol**

This common theme is used as a metaphor for God’s people who are either faithful and pure, or, rebellious.  These include:

- The parable of the two adulterous sisters and their children (Eze 23)
- The daughter of Babylon vs the daughter of Zion (Zech 2:7, 10).
- More generally, the Old Testament uses this image of a woman to represent either faithful (Isa 62:5, Jer 2:1, 2) or unfaithful (Isa 47:1-3, Jer 2:32, Eze 16, Nah 3:4, 5) groups of people.  See also Gal 4:21-31 which used Sarah and Hagar as metaphors.
- In the book of Revelation, we have two women: Jezebel or the harlot as a symbol of Babylon (Rev 2:20, 17:1-18:24), vs, the pure woman as a symbol of God’s faithful people the bride of the Lamb (Rev 12:1-17, 19:7, 21:9).

**APPENDIX 2 - Interpretations of the early Church Fathers of Rev 12's "Woman"**

- Hyppolytus, Part II Dogmatical and Historical Treatise on Christ and Antichrist, section 66.  The "woman" is understood to be the church
- Methodius, "The banquet of the 10 Virgins, or, concerning chastity", discourse VII, "Procilla", chapter V. The "woman" is understood to be the church
- The Shepherd of Hermas, First Book (Visions), fourth Vision, chapter II. The "woman" is understood to be the church